# Python sorted() function key = lambda, index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, lambda, index-error

I was trying to use the built-in sorted function in Python3 and have run into a key indexing problem.
If I have:

`sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key = lambda items: unsorted_list[2], reverse = True)`

where my unsorted list is a list of tuples of length 3. This line is supposed to sort the unsorted list based on the 3rd value in the tuple.

The issue is that the line runs into an error if the list you try to sort is of length <=2. with a list index out of range error. If I run it with a list of greater length it works just fine.

when I try and replace the index with -1 instead, since it's the last value in the list it works just fine.

`sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key = lambda items: unsorted_list[-1], reverse = True)`

Is this a known error in the sorted() function, I'm figuring maybe the interpreter sees that unsorted_list[2] is nonexistent, so the expression fails before the lambda expression is evaluated, or am I misunderstanding something about the sorted() function?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to index into `items` (which represents each tuple in `unsorted_list`) in the `key` function , not `unsorted_list` itself:

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda items: items[-1], reverse=True)
```

Example:

```
unsorted_list = [('', '', 2), ('', '', 3), ('', '', 1)]
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda items: items[-1], reverse=True)
print(sorted_list)
```

outputs

```
[('', '', 3), ('', '', 2), ('', '', 1)]
```